# The usage of 'of' to indicate date. Do I need 'th' or not?

Tags: grammar

Which is correct,

29th of September
or
29 of September?
or both are correct?

Comment: This question depends on context. There is no single answer.

Comment: what context???

Comment: If in your own head you spell it out entirely in words not figures or abbreviations and leave nothing out or assumed, then you shall have your answer for how it would be read aloud. *On the twenty-ninth of September*.

Answer (score -1):

Between the two examples in your question it would always be "[the] 29th of September". Contrary to the comment saying it depends on context, I cannot think of any case where you would ever say "29 of September". However, in what I understand to be British or Commonwealth usage, you might write "29 September", although I don't know if you'd say it out loud. But as an American I would not say or write it like that (I would say or write "September 29th", and I'd probably use that in preference to either of the examples in your question.)

Comment: I always thought (as a Brit) that it was the Americans who wrote day numbers non-ordinally (30 June and not 30th June). In an expression involving 'the' and 'of' I would always use the ordinal form (**the** 29th **of** June). Never "29 of September".

Comment: Interesting, maybe I'm wrong about who writes it that way! I'm a Californian and I wouldn't write "30 June", but I can imagine it's some other American regional dialect or something. Presumably whoever downvoted my answer also disagrees, but since they haven't commented it's hard to know why! ;-)